# C# visual studio. Is it possible to use the same name for many controls?

Tags: c#

I'm new to Visual Studio. I'm making an GUI for my C# application.

Is it possible to use different namespaces for the GUI controls?

For example if I use two GroupBoxes to group RadioButtons. Could I reuse the radiobutton names in the second groupbox?

Is it possible to use the same name within different namespaces in the GUI?

It seems stupid if I must come up with new names for everything.

Comment: When programming with MVVM at least, you *usually* don't even need control names.

Comment: For now, when you see something in programming that "seems stupid", just go straight to the assumption that you know quite a bit less than you think you do. No heuristic is infallible, but that one has served me very well for decades now, at least when when I have the good sense to use it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Even *without* MVVM you should need them very rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two controls with the same name in the same object.

It sounds like what you should be doing is creating a new `UserControl`, because you logically have a self-contained object that is your `GroupBox` (or perhaps the containing object(s)) with radio buttons under it.  If you pull out the user control then the items under it can have a different name in the user control definition, and you could access those objects though different instances of the named user control.

Comment: An added benefit of this approach is the ability to specifically hunt your specific control down in a collection by its `Type`.

Comment: I took the time to learn about user controls. And this was what I was searching for.